# Excel synchronize workbooks with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to ask if you could help me with copying some worksheet data from workbook A into my active workbook (workbook B)

I have the following code in the main workbook to copy the data from workbook A

```vb
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    test

End Sub


Sub test()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim MainBook As Workbook

    'Open All workbooks first:
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Folder\WorkbookA.xlsm")
'Set MainBook = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
Set MainBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

'Now, copy what you want from wb1:
Wb1.Sheets("Projekte").Cells.Copy
'Now, paste to Main worksheet:
MainBook.Worksheets("Projekte").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Close Wb's:
    Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

I know, that it opens worksheet A and that it highlights and copys the data.

The script wont paste it into worksheet B (where the script is executed from)

Anybody know what i did wrong?

Kindest regards, and thanks for any help !

Comment: find and learn the difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` I guess `Wb1` and `MainBook` are the same workbook, because after opening `WorkbookA.xlsm` this one is the active one, and therefore you paste exactly there where you copied from.

Comment: Oh wow, that was the solution.
Sometimes I am just blind. Thank you verry much!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Mainbook (destination) first before the origin (if you're going to use `ActiveWorkbook`).

```
'Set MainBook First
   Set MainBook = ThisWorkbook
'Open All workbook:
   Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Folder\WorkbookA.xlsm")
```

Just for clarity, it's just me being OC on this one.

Comment: no need to set it **first** if you use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, it will also work after setting `Wb1`

Answer (score 0):

you have to properly reference your workbook and worksheet objects

if you have to paste the whole content of range (including formatting, comments, ...), then you want to code like follows (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet 'store currently active sheet
    Workbooks.Open("Z:\Folder\WorkbookA.xlsm").Sheets("Projekte").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1") ' open the wanted workbook and copy its "Projekte" sheet used range to 'targetSheet (i.e.: the sheet in the workbook where it all started) from its cell A1
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False ' close the currently active workbook (i.e. the just opened one)
End Sub
```

if you only need to paste values, then this is the way to go (much faster!):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet 'store currently active sheet

    With Workbooks.Open("Z:\Folder\WorkbookA.xlsm").Sheets("Projekte").UsedRange ' open the wanted workbook and reference its sheet "Projekte" used range
        targetSheet.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        .Parent.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close the parent workbook of referenced range (i.e., the newly opened workbook)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` is the same bad practice like using `.Select` and `.Activate` and `Selection.` I highly recommend **never** to use them unless you really really have to. In 99.9% there is a solution that avoids them. You can never say for 100% sure which workbook is the currently `ActiveWorkbook` is. I recommend to read about `ThisWorkbook` which makes your code much more reliable, because in 99.9% this is what you were looking for. Another recommendation: Never use `Sheets` if you can use `Worksheets` only use `Sheets` if you cannot use `Worksheets` and you know why.

Comment: @Peh, in this context, `Sub Test()` is being called by a `Worksheet_Activate()` event handler hence `ActiveSheet` is the only way to go and know what sheet are we dealing with. As for the `ActiveWorkbook` reference, again  it's been used right after an opening of a new workbook so I'd assume it's safe using it, but should it be prone to some workbook opening process delay not affecting `ThisWorkbook` reference (that changes at every workbook opening, too), then we could use this latter. Or we could use `With Workbooks.Open(...) .. End With`. Finally, what's the issue with using `Sheets` here?

Comment: I know that your code works, but I still recommend not to use `ActiveWorkbook`. As you see at the OPs question, people (beginners) don't understand why `ActiveWorkbook` works in your code but does not if they copy it into their code (e.g after an `Workbooks.Open`), they just expect something else. I've just seen too many people running into issues using `ActiveWorkbook` where they wouldn't have run into if they used `ThisWorkbook` what they actually meant. It's not about that there is something wrong with your code, but code with `ActiveWorkbook` is just harder to maintain than `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @Peh. I see. So `ActiveSheet` usage is no longer an issue here, right? While even `ThisWorkbook` isn't that safe since it always references the Workbook the currently running macro resides in, so that if your "main" macro calls another macro from a different workbook then `ThisWorkbook` changes to reference this latter. Finally, as for the `Sheets` we can agree it's safe here, can't we? Anyway, I think this is a good discussion

Comment: I mean your code actually has no real issues. I just recommended, didn't mean you are not allowed to use `ActiveWorkbook` at all. I mean if I write `ActiveWorkbook` then this assumes that the code runs using the currently active workbook (no matter which one is active, it should work on every workbook that is active). If the success of running the code depends on that you (or your code) selected a **specific** workbook before using `ActiveWorkbook` then you did something which I called a bad practice, because then it would be a good idea to reference that specific workbook.

Comment: Same for `Sheets` I mean if my code runs well no matter if the sheet called "Projekte" is a sheet or a chart then use `Sheets` if it only runs well if the sheet called "Projekte" is a worksheet then use `Worksheets`. In this case if the sheet "Projekte" was a chart the code would fail so I would say `Worksheets` was the more correct term here even if `Sheets` worked too **in this case**. It's just more precise, the more precise you are the less can go wrong. Hopefully I could explain well what I meant to tell.

Comment: @Peh, I see, again. So, while confirming that `ActiveSheet` was an _unavoidable_ reference here, I think that the `Sheets`/`Worksheets` piece of advice is not as general as you're depicting: I'd say you 1) _have_ to use `Worksheets` in code where you want to loop through them only and use methods or properties that wouldn't be allowed in chart sheets. 2 _have_ to use `Sheets` when you want to loop through chart sheets only. 3) use whatever reference when your code is using hard coded sheets names, since you must know what you're doing and  a Worksheet and a Chart sheet can't have the same name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165136/discussion-between-p-and-displayname).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is never to use `ActiveWorkbook`.

In most cases when people use `ActiveWorkbook` they actually meant to use `ThisWorkbook`. The difference is:

- `ActiveWorkbook` is the currently selected one which is "on top of the screen" in exact that moment when your code runs. That can be any workbook the user just clicked on while your code runs. So you never can be 100% sure to get the right workbook.
- `ThisWorkbook` is the actual workbook your code runs at the moment. And this doesn't change ever. So this is a well defined reference and no gamble about which workbook is on top at the moment.

**About why your approach did not work**

```
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Folder\WorkbookA.xlsm") 'this line makes WorkbookA the active one
Set MainBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook 'this makes MainBook = WorkbookA
```

Therefore a simple `Set MainBook = Application.ThisWorkbook` should work here.

**Another recommendation**

`Sheets` and `Worksheets` is not the same. Make sure you never use `Sheets` when you can use `Worksheets`.

- `Sheets` contains worksheets and charts
- `Worksheets` contain only worksheets

An example `Sheets(1).Range("A1")` fails if it is a chart.